# a transaction should not proceed due to the condition set but when i try it but it still continues. What could I be doing wrong?

Tags: java, boolean

I'm using java for the programming language. a user is asked to input card combination, it'll decide if it's a decide if it's a debit or a credit or expired (ex. 9876-STB0-2522-AERG ) and when a combination 2522 appears on the third row, the transaction should not proceed because that means the card is expired. Else the transaction can proceed.

But in this code, despite putting a combination with 2522 in it like this
Card-Id: 9876-STB0-2522-AERG
it still proceeds to ask the savings.
What could i be doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardTransactionSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        

        System.out.print("Card-id: ");

        String cardId = scanner.nextLine();

        

        String expirationCode = cardId.substring(8, 12);

        if (expirationCode.equals("2522")) {

            System.out.println("TRANSACTION ERROR:");

            System.out.println("Card-id: " + cardId);

            System.out.println("The card is expired, and no transaction can occur.");

            System.exit(0);

        }

        

        boolean isCreditCard = checkIfCreditCard(cardId);

        if (isCreditCard) {

            

        } else {

           

            System.out.print("Savings: ");

            double savings = scanner.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Amount to pay: ");

            double amountToPay = scanner.nextDouble();

            if (amountToPay > savings) {

                System.out.println("TRANSACTION ERROR:");

                System.out.println("Card-id: " + cardId);

                System.out.println("Savings: " + savings);

                System.out.println("Amount to pay: " + amountToPay);

                System.out.println("Transaction cannot proceed.");

            } else {

                System.out.println("DEBIT:");

                System.out.println("Card-id: " + cardId);

                System.out.println("Savings: " + savings);

                System.out.println("Amount to pay: " + amountToPay);

                double newBalance = savings - amountToPay;

                System.out.println("New balance: " + newBalance);

            }

        }

        scanner.close();

    }

    private static boolean checkIfCreditCard(String cardId) {

        String cardType = cardId.substring(0, 4);

        String[] creditCardTypes = {"AABB", "1234", "IT22", "BSIT", "AAAA", "ABAB", "STB0", "0000"};

        for (String type : creditCardTypes) {

            if (type.equals(cardType)) {

                return true;

            }

        }

        return false;

    }

    private static double getCreditLimit(String cardId) {

        String creditLimitType = cardId.substring(12);

        switch (creditLimitType) {

            case "AAAA":

                return 800_000.00;

            case "BBBB":

                return 700_000.00;

            case "CCCC":

                return 600_000.00;

            case "DDDD":

                return 500_000.00;

            case "EEEE":

                return 400_000.00;

            default:

                return 300_000.00;

        }

    }

    private static double calculateMonthlyDue(double amount, int months) {

        if (months == 12) {

            return (amount * 1.02) / months;

        } else {

            return amount / months;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you printed the expirationCode to see what you got vs what you expect ?

Comment: Are you considering - (dash) in input string?